# NaN issues on my sum of values in my array of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have been building this APP in VUE.js , but have a little issue on one function where in im trying to add the values of each object inside the array..throwing me a NaN error.Lets say

```
script

data(){
 return{
    array:[
      { product_name: "Chain Saw",
       product_free: 2,
       product_free_discount: 306.8,
       product_id: 1,
      }
      { product_name: "Ox",
       product_free: 1,
       product_free_discount: 60.8,
       product_id: 1,
      }
  ],
  totalDiscEquals:0,
 }
}
```

then on my computed property i just set this function

```
COMPUTED
totalDiscObUnique() {
      let total = this.array.reduce(

        (a, b) => a + b.product_free_discount,
        0
      );
      console.log(total);

      return this.totalDiscEquals=total;
    },
```

creating the process in the created module like this

```
created(){
this.totalDiscObUnique;
```

but the when i console log the value of totalDisEquals, throws me a NaN result , any idea about why is this happening, or sugerences about why NaN mostly times ocurr for?

Comment: If I fix the syntax error in `data` (missing `,`), that code works just fine with that array: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/9xov8mw2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    array:[
      { 
        product_name: "Chain Saw",
        product_free: 2,
        product_free_discount: 306.8,
        product_id: 1,
      }, // <--- [1] missing comma here (,)
      { 
        product_name: "Ox",
        product_free: 1,
        product_free_discount: 60.8,
        product_id: 1,
      }
    ],
    totalDiscEquals:0,
  },
  
  /* [2] It's not recommended to assign new value to a data property
 in a computed, instead it intended to give you just a filtered / reduced
 / ... response.  */
  computed: {
    totalDiscObUnique() {
      return this.array.reduce((a, b) => a + b.product_free_discount, 0);
    },
  },
  
  created () {
    /* [3] also, there is no need to reassign the same value to a new
 data property again, instead you can use the computed itself wherever you
 want to use it */
    // this.totalDiscEquals = this.totalDiscObUnique
    console.log(this.totalDiscObUnique)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
 {{ totalDiscObUnique }}
</div>
```